# Почему при выгрузке товаров в формат xml (yml) битрикс создает символы «+++» и «===» в description?

Tags: html, xml, битрикс, yml

Я выгружаю товары из каталога в файл xml.
У каждого товара есть двухколоночная таблица где прописаны технические характеристики в формате "ключ - значение". то есть

```
<table>
<tr><td>Длина линейки</td><td>2800 мм</td></tr>
<tr><td>Ширина раскроя</td><td>1800 мм</td></tr>
</table>
```

Я засунул эту таблицу в тег description при экспорте. 
В итоге в xml все description имеют вот такой вид:

```
<description>Длина линейки===2800 мм+++
Ширина раскроя===1800 мм+++
Максимальная высота настила===210 мм+++
Напряжение===220В+++
Частота тока===50+++
Габариты===760*460*190+++
Вес брутто/нетто===32/28+++</description>
```

В связи с этим вопросы:

- Откуда взялись знаки "+++" и "==="?
- Если в description не требуется вставлять таблицу характеристик, тогда куда следует ее вставить?
- Если эти знаки - 
  "нормальное явление", то, при загрузке на маркет, могут ли они появиться в    описании к товару?

Comment: Смотрите на компонент который генерирует xml-файл.

Comment: Я могу уточнить? По какой причине возникли эти символы? Будут ли эти символы в маркете в описании к товару? Как правильно вставлять таблицы в xml?

Comment: Сейчас видно, что эти символы ставятся вместо тегов. То есть работает замена тегов. Ее делает компонент выгрузки скорее всего. Хотите изменить/убрать - модифицируйте обработку выгрузки.